# Is the projective space a quasi-affine variaty?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

A quasi-affin variety in $\mathbb{A}^n$ is a zariski-open set in an irreducible variety. It's true that $\mathbb{P}^k$ is isomorphic as an algebraic variety to a quasi-affin variety in some $\mathbb{A}^n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a projective variety there are no globally defined non-constant regular functions. Suppose you have a morphism  from $X$  to an affine space.  Any morphism  to $\mathbf{A}^n$ by composing with the co-ordinate projections gives a global regular function on $X$. So all co-ordinate projections are constants. So the map on $X$ is constant and cannot provide an embedding into an affine space.